# How to to pass iterators to the std::lower_bound() comparison function?

Tags: c++, std, stl-algorithm

In the following declaration borrowed from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/)

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class T, class Compare>
ForwardIterator lower_bound(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val, Compare comp);
```

`comp()` should resemble something like this:

```
template<class T>
bool comp(const T& v1, const T& v2);
```

The problem is that I don't want to pass the value type there. I want to pass iterators to it and then <s>shift them</s> okay, just stare at them silently inside `comp()` before dereferencing. (Not to mention - log them.) Is there any workaround for this?

Of course, I can write my own container class with its own iterators, and of course I can write my own implementation of `std::lower_bound()`. Both options are rather unpleasant.

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? The things you say you want to do in `comp` don't make much sense to me. Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Mm, this _would_ be kind of useful. I'd check in Boost but otherwise yeah roll your own.

Comment: @YSC "Are your iterators ContiguousIterator?" - For now, they are. I'm ready to go with `std::vector` as a container here. Does it help anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

> The signature of the predicate function should be equivalent to the
>   following:
>
> `bool pred(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);`
>
> The signature does not need to have `const &`, but the function must not
>   modify the objects passed to it.

So you can not, and should not, do this. `std::lower_bound` has specific purpose and it should not modify the input in any way. Write your own function for this purpose.

---

If you need indices only, and your container stores its elements in linear, continuous block of memory, you could do this (example with `std::vector`):

```
std::vector<...> vec;
...
const auto* firstElemPtr = &vec[0];
std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), key, [firstElemPtr](const auto& left, const auto& right) -> bool {
  size_t index = &left - firstElemPtr;
  // now do the comparison
});
```

Comment: I won't modify any input. Solemn promise. Let's say that container is a vector and I just want to log the indices for debugging purposes.

Comment: When OP writes they want to "shift the iterators", I'm not sure they wants to actually bitshift values here.

Comment: @sigil If it's all about indices, it can be done under certain conditions, see update.

Comment: I thought about it and wrote an answer with this idea, but I fear `comp` must be called at some point with `key` as a parameter. Taking the address of `key` and treating it as an array is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @YSC "When OP writes they want to "shift the iterators", I'm not sure they wants to actually bitshift values here." - Not a bit shift. To tell the truth, it's a sorted vector with rotation applied to it. Something like {4, 5, 1, 2, 3}. My plan is to compensate for the rotation by shifting the indices back into place inside `comp()`.

Comment: "The type `Type1` must be such that an object of type `ForwardIt` can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to `Type1`. The type `Type2` must be such that an object of type `T` can be implicitly converted to `Type2`." `&right` is *always* `&key`

Comment: @Caleth thank you. I've updated my answer from your "intel".

Comment: So, the `size_t leftIndex = &left - firstElemPtr;` part hinges on the assumption that references are implemented as pointers and taking one's address would get us into the right place of the container. I guess it should work as of now, but with no guarantees.

Comment: Okay, put it into my code and it works. Actually, I used the form YSC offered but marking your answer anyway because you were the first with this idea.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`std::lower_bound` doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), one can read for `bool comp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);`:

> The type `Type1` must be such that an object of type `ForwardIt` can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to `Type1`. The type `Type2` must be such that an object of type `T` can be implicitly converted to `Type2`. ​

This means, `std::lower_bound` will always call `comp` with an element from the range as the left hand side argument, and `value` as the right hand side argument. If your search range is a contiguous range (meaning you're dealing with `std::vector`, `std::array`, `std::valarray`, `std::string`, ..., or C-style arrays), you can devise an iterator from the distance between the range's start and `comp`'s left hand side argument:

```
auto v = std::vector<int>{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

auto comp = [&v](const int &lhs, const int &rhs)
{
    auto it_lhs = cbegin(v) + std::distance(std::addressof(*cbegin(v)), &lhs);
    return *it_lhs < rhs;
};

std::cout << *std::lower_bound(begin(v), end(v), 2, comp) << "\n";
```

Comment: Man, it's sort of obvious that `lower_bound()` won't accept iterators directly - it's, like, in its prototype. What I'm asking for is a workaround. Maybe there's another function that does what I want. Or maybe there's a trick like the one Mateusz Grzejek has suggested. Gonna try that one in the meanwhile.

Comment: @sigil you cannot devise an iterator from `value`; [see for yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c270c6b40f3f6ce). This is UB. like SIGSEGV UB. It would only kind of work if you were guaranteed `value` is always the right hand side argument of `comp`. But I would not advise taking this implementation detail into account.

Comment: @sigil my bad, it _is_ guaranteed. Updated.